# How to create email addresses for a website

Tags: email, web, dns, email-address

I have recently created a website for a client. He has asked repeatedly if I can get email addresses for the website i.e. help@mywebsite.com.

I haven't a clue where to start.

I've found out that the site I created is based on linode. Anyone know how to derive email accounts from that platform?

Comment: I know i can create emails in the website panel when i log in through the webadmin panel (your backend of the website) so if you registered your space and your domain, its where you have the space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions, but I have used google apps to create a few emails for my website. Google apps provides a good solid interface, where you can make several email accounts for free, as long as you prove that the domain is yours.

A link to the google apps website:

You can either get an upgraded or free version.

[GOOGLE APPS](http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/pricing.html)

Answer (score 1):

you would have to look into your website hosting provider/server. In the control/web panel (file management tool), there should be instructions on how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to go through whatever hosting service he/you are using. If it's a shared host, there should be a place in the admin control panel (typically CPanel) to add email addresses. If you're on a dedicated host, it's a little more complicated. Google it.

Answer (score 1):

Check with your Web Hosting provider.

Even the smallest packages give you the option to have at least 1 email address.

Answer (score 1):

- Log into your Hosting Provider's website.
- In the web panel under your registered domain / server there should be an option somewhere to create mailbox / email / email address.
- If you can't find it - Make sure you can create email addresses with your current hosting package (This is usually always the case, described under 'Mailboxes') / email or contact your hosting provider to ask for assistance.

Hope this helps.